# Excel table only partly pasting into powerpoiint

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerpoint

I'm trying to paste a table into powerpoint and for some reason only part of the table is showing. I need to use copy/paste link as this powerpoint is often updated by different people every month. The table is only 5 columns by 8 rows, so it's really small. All that displays in powerpoint is 3 columns and 5 rows.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would it be good enough to take a screenshot and paste that in?

Comment: Why not link a table, from Excel to PPT, instead? Then update the Excel table in Excel. No problems of copy/paste and all is well.